# Optimal Way to Load Objects in an HttpPost Action Method in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3 and Entity Framework 4.1.

I was wondering what is the preferred method of updating a object when not all of the properties are provided in the HTTP Post.

For example, an Order object may have the properties of Items, CreateDate and UpdateDate. In an edit form only the Items property will be entered and posted to the Edit ActionMethod. So the below basic code will fail as the CreateDate and UpdateDate properties are not included with the order.

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Order order)
    { 
        {

            db.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
        return View(order);
    }
```

What is the best way to handle this situation? For simple objects such as this order I suppose the CreateDate and UpdateDate can be kept in hidden fields, however, for more complex objects (such as those with several one-to-many relationships) should the object id be used to retrieve the full object and then overwrite some of its properties with the values posted back in the form...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create view models

```
public class OrderEditModel
{
   //properties used in the view
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(OrderEditModel orderEditModel)
{ 

    // map OrderEditModel to Order

    db.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

You can use AutoMapper to map them

Other option is to retrieve the object from database and update it

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(string id)
{ 
    var order = db.Orders.FindByKey(id);

    UpdateModel(order);

    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Using the second method would I not need to use public ActionResult Edit(string id, FormCollection formValues) to pass the form values for use by the UpdateModel method?

Comment: @Judo yes. pass `FormCollection` also

Answer (score 1):

In the scenario, where the createdate and modifydate are in hidden inputs on the Form that posted (named createDate and modDate), then you can retrieve them from the request form collection as follows, even though they are not on the Order object.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Order order)
{ 
    var createdOn = this.Request.Form["createDate"];
    var editedOn = this.Request.Form["modDate"];

    db.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Im not sure how this would assign those values to the order object. Wouldnt I need to  order.createDate = this.Request.Form["createDate"];

Comment: I thought the issues was that your Order object didnt have those properties, but they were in the View and needed in the Action.  Is that inaccurate?

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer. The order object has the CreateDate and UpdateDate properties but they are not part of the update form posted to the Edit ActionResult.

Comment: Got it, I would either add them as hidden inputs as you suggested or, in the Edit (post) action retrieve the latest state from the DB, mutate the instance, update the ModifyDate to DateTime.Now and finally, update.